# Material-UI Drawer: How to position drawer in a specific div

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using [Material-UI React Drawer](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/). Is there a way I can have the drawer confined to a specific section of my page instead of occupying the entire window? I have tried giving the root component an absolute position instead of fixed but this does not change the placement of the drawer.

```
<div className="confirmation-drawer">
   <Drawer
       anchor="top" 
       open={state.top} 
       onClose={toggleDrawer('top', false)}>
      <!-- Drawer content goes here -->
    </Drawer>
</div>
```

I need the drawer inside the `.confirmation-drawer` div and not the entire page. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Add display: 'flex' to parent of your 2 child components of page

Comment: I am not sure I understand you @niks. Which 2 child components are you referring to?

Comment: one is your drawer and other is anything that other side you want to be

Comment: I wonder how it should look? `Drawer` has absolute position by definition (left, right etc.)

Comment: related? https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/11749#issuecomment-781249906

Answer (score 7):

try this:

```
import {styled, Drawer as MuiDrawer} from '@mui/material'

const Drawer = styled(MuiDrawer)({
    position: "relative", //imp
    width: 240, //drawer width
    "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
      width: 240, //drawer width
      position: "absolute", //imp
      transition: "none !important"
    }
})
```

If you want transitions then use [collapse](https://mui.com/components/transitions/#collapse).

```
<Collapse orientation='horizontal' in={open} >
 <Box> ... </Box>
</Collapse>
```

Comment: I recently upgraded from v4 to v5 which broke the Drawers that were directly attached in a Popup. Thanks for Hint on the Collapse :)

Comment: Using Collapse instead of trying to hack the Drawer functionality was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

The code below worked for me. It uses the preferred [one-off styling method](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#1-one-off-customization) in the MUI docs. Transitions work without any additional tweaks. Of course make sure you have a *'relative'* element up in the DOM tree.

```
<Drawer
  sx={{
    '& .MuiDrawer-root': {
        position: 'absolute'
    },
    '& .MuiPaper-root': {
        position: 'absolute'
    },
  }}
>
</Drawer>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I have it immediately inside another `<Box position='relative'>`, but it still appears absolutely positioned on the left-hand side of the screen. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

what @Jon Deavers said is true, though there is a workaround. you can find the `z-index` of the drawer overlay (1300 in may case) and set a higher `z-index` to the component you wish to be on top. then just set paddings inside the drawer so all it's content is visible.

as i said its merely a workaround but i hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score -1):

The Drawer component is a nav menu component that is designed to overlay the application and not to be nested inside a container. It will always appear over your other content.

If you are looking to have a dynamic element in which you can hide information and other interactive components you may want to take a look at the Accordion component from MUI.

https://material-ui.com/api/accordion/

That will allow you to have a small "drawer"-like element that other components can be hidden inside of.

Comment: good but to be like the drawer it needs to come in from the side.

Comment: Accordion falls way short of fulfilling the design spec, also doesnt it defeat the purpose of component based design when you enforce such conditions on usage. 9/10 times you want the banner or toolbar to actually span the entire view... and not have the sidemenu going all the way to the corner

Comment: Accordion definitely falls short of what the OP is requesting. There's also situations where you still require a menu-like experience, but you don't need it in the nav, but further down.